# Tomcat login redirect NullPointerException in FormAuthenticator

Tags: java, session, tomcat, web-applications, nullpointerexception

I'm really having a difficult time with a web app that I'm deploying to my company's tomcat server. I can deploy it to my own test server and access just fine, but when I deploy it to the test server and access the app, it shows a blank page and logs the following error:

```
Apr 26, 2013 12:22:42 PM org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter service
SEVERE: An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.saveRequest(FormAuthenticator.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:238)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I've already spent hours on this. I would really appreciate your help! Thanks! :)

Comment: More details would help, such as what version of tomcat, what is the software stack etc.

Comment: Looks like you have a `null` session

Comment: For software stack, it's primarily a backbone.js webapp that connects to a RESTful service and has a few Java Web Servlets. I don't think the problem was with the code, just the project structure. I can't just upload the code since it's a work project, but I'll let you know if I figure out a better solution. And, yes, I think you're right about the null session. Why it was null is the question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. The problem was with my IntelliJ artifact building configuration. I just had to make sure it was actually including my compiled Java code in the build. I checked the "Build on make" checkbox and included the project module's compile output.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a semi-reasonable workaround by building the project in netbeans instead of IntelliJ. Probably has something to do with how the project has been structured, but I don't have time to worry about it right now.